# Overload c++ operator >> so i can read a vector (vector <int> vector;)

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, operator-keyword

i want to know how i can overload the >> operator so i can read a vector or a matrix just doing cin >> vector vector().

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far? [This should be doable in about three lines above and beyond the regular `operator << ` boilerplate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  template <typename T>
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& v) {
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(is), std::istream_iterator<T>(),
              std::back_inserter(v));
    return is;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using namespace std; and the sizes of the vectors have been assigned before you read them, this will work.

```
template<class T> istream& operator>>(istream &is,vector<T> &V){
    for(auto &x : V) is >> x;
    return is;
}
template<class T> istream& operator>>(istream &is,vector<vector<T>> &V){
    for(auto &x : V) is >> x;
    return is;
}
```